# How I can stop the printer function?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

```
    from tkinter import *
    
    root = Tk()
    
    #This function should stop the function printer
    def button_status(is_clicked):
        return is_clicked
    
    #This function prints integer numbers from 0 to 2
    def printer():
        for i in range(3):
            print(i)
            if(button_status==True):
                break
                
    button = Button(root, text="Stampa",height=2, width=6, command= printer, font=("TkDefaultFont",18),bg='white')
    button.place(x=630, y=680)    
    button3 = Button(root, text="Termina",height=2, width=6, command= lambda: button_status(True), font=("TkDefaultFont",18),bg='white')
    button3.place(x=780, y=680)
    
    print(button_status)
    root.state('zoomed')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: close window of Tk()!

Answer (score 0):

There are a things you'll need to change in your code to allow one function to control the behavior of the other.

The first thing that needs to change is that `printer` needs not to be using a Python loop. If it does that, `tkinter` won't have any opportunity to run any other code, since it will be waiting for the `printer` function to return first. Instead, make the button that calls `printer` the first time pass in a number and have the function schedule itself to be called again by the tkinter main loop after a short delay.

```
def printer(i):
    print(i)                            # Note, this always prints at least once. Move the
    if i < 2 and not button_status:     # print call inside the `if` if you don't want that.
        root.after(1000, printer, i+1)  # Schedule ourselves to be called again in one second

button = Button(root, text="Stampa",height=2, width=6, command=lambda: printer(0),
                font=("TkDefaultFont",18),bg='white')
button.place(x=630, y=680)
```

The other thing you need to change is some way of sharing state between the two functions. The easiest way to do that would be with a global variable, but you might consider redesigning your two functions as methods of a class instead, so that they can share state via instance variables instead. Here's what the global variable setup would look like (`printer` above will already work with this code):

```
button_status = False     # Set an initial value

def stop_counting():
    global button_status  # This tells Python we want to be able to change the global variable
    button_status = True  # Use `button_status = not button_status` if you want it to toggle

button3 = Button(root, text="Termina",height=2, width=6, command=stop_counting,
                 font=("TkDefaultFont",18),bg='white')
button3.place(x=780, y=680)
```